# removing duplicates keys from returned hashmap

Tags: hashmap

im having an issue where im getting duplicate keys from HashMap, in the UI it appears as
for example:

Header

- List item

Header

- List item

Header

- List item

i want to show them as follows in the UI(expected)

Header

- List item
- List item
- List item

can any one please help me with this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your post to include the **language you're using** and a [mcve] showing the relevant parts of what you're trying at the moment. Looking at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would be a good idea. Otherwise how can we possibly try to help you find what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make your hash map something like `HashMap<String, List<Object>>`, that way a single `String` can map to multiple Objects.

Comment: In the future, check that your formatting actually displays something that makes sense.

Comment: didn't think it was necessary. Thanks for the remainder. Don't know if Object must be tagged as code though.